# Android Notification App

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I'm currently working on an android application. I have to log any new installed app name whenever the user is installing/downloading a new third party app. How can I get the notification if the user is installing a new app. Thanks in advance.

### Java File

```
public class ApplicationBroadcastService extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.print("-------");
    }
}
```

### Manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".applicationlog.ApplicationBroadcastService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"  />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

But still I do not enter the onReceive method, when I am installing/uninstalling any app.

Here is the solution:

I did a small change in my Manifest file.

```
    <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"  />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Now it's working fine.. :)
Thanks again @willytate

Comment: Is there any launcher activity in your code?Will you please share your whole code because I tried your code but its not working for me.

Comment: How to trigger onReceive if app is not running in background.if app is running onReceive methode for Package_ADDED and REMOVED working.But i need to trigger Even app is not running please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ajay,

You will need to setup a `BroadcastReceiver` with an intent filter to receive the following Action: [`ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) then from the `onReceive()` method of the BroadcastReceiver you can launch a `Notification`.

Comment: @willylate, Please see my code. i am still not get into onReceive method. correct me if i have done something wrong.

Comment: well, i know to receive `PACKAGE_REMOVED` you need the permission `BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED`.  Try just setting the receiver line to `<receiver android:name=".ApplicationBroadcastService">` that usually works fo rme.

Comment: How could i get the name or the info about the last installed app... Thanks

Comment: You could try using the `EXTRA_UID` value that is passed in with the data during this intent.  It should give you the ID value of the last app installed.  Use this information to retrieve more information about the app from `PackageManager`.  This is just an educated guess though...

Comment: @WilliamTate Is there any launcher activity in your code?Will you please share your whole code because I tried your code but its not working for me

Comment: @nitishpatel Full source code can be found here: https://github.com/willtate/Will-Deux  keep in mind this question is almost 2 years old (so is my source) and Android has progressed by leaps and bounds since then!  good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). You are looking for `ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL` (which seems to be never used, see comments) and `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`.

Comment: nope, try to implement what willytate mentioned. Nobody will write code for you. If you stuck, ask a new question (and don't ask for code there, present what you have...)

Comment: Thanks @WarrenFaith, your answer was not very clear to me.that's why i ask for some clue. anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: The docs say ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL was never used.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL

Comment: thanks for saying, for the time this was written, it wasn't mentioned in the documentation...

Answer (score 3):

You can listen for the `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` intent.