# How to block app installation with a program?

Tags: android

Android market has a lot of application to protect access to applications, block app instalation, etc.

I read about Intent on Android, but I don´t know how applications like "Application Protection" block access to Phone App or block new app installation always asking for a password. Anyone have an ideia?

Comment: Not sure I can help but do you mean like the Prey tracking app. This lets you stop someone uninstalling the app w/o permission.

Comment: So, it´s a similar, the real problem is: I have a corporate a app running on Android phones, so I didn´t want the users using browser, gmail,facebook, or games app. I need to block for the use only my app.

Comment: Oh I see you want to "lock down" the phone? If so this isn't really the site you want to post the question on. Have you tried superuser.com?

Comment: But I need do this in code, not using a app.

Comment: You want an app to lock down what other apps can be run on a phone? Why complicate this? I can fully understand why Google would not provide you with the tools to do this in the SDK! I don't even know if you can do it... Have you tried superuser or the android enthusiasts stack exchanges?

Comment: check these answers...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900928/uninstall-app-silently-with-system-priveleges

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499025/android-notification-app