# Can we uninstall application without user's consent

Tags: android, apk, android-package-managers

Trying to developing multiple apps in which I have a Main app. All other apps are kind of supportive ones.

Can we uninstall support apps if the Main app is uninstalled by user. If so, what changes would it require to do in all apps.

As I know using `Action_DELETE` it will ask user's consent to uninstall the app but I want to uninstall without that.

Comment: What's wrong with asking the user?

Comment: @OlafDietsche: There can be multiple apps so I don't want user to be bugged. Also those apps would be useless if Main App is uninstalled.

Comment: I asked, because I would be upset, if anyone removed apps without asking.

Comment: If the only purpose of these apps is to support your main app, reconsider your architecture. You could easily do all of this in one app.

Comment: without root permissions you cannot uninstall any app without user permission

Comment: @NishantPardamwar So if we gain system level permission of app than it can be achieved and not for 3rd party am I right?

Comment: **pm uninstall** commands needs **android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL** permission which has **signature** only permission, so it wont work unless your apk is signed with same certificate as your system.

you can check [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: there is other way which you can checkout [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900928/uninstall-app-silently-with-system-priveleges)

Comment: @NishantPardamwar Thanks for the info.. Its really helpfull.