# How to install/uninstall android app in background?

Tags: java, android, security, apk, android-install-apk

I want to `install/uninstall` apps silently without user confirmation dialog. I tried two solutions, rooted device and install app in system directory, but found a better solution mentioned in this [site](https://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/apk-with-system-privileges/).

> To achieve that first you have to obtain the certificates that were used to sign the Android OS installed on the device – a pair of certificates (.pk8 + x509.pem) – to generate a java certificate.
>
> The certificates pair (platform.pk8 + platform.x509.pem) can be found under {Android Source}/build/target/product/security.`

I downloaded the certificate pair from [source code for 4.1.2 android version](http://androidxref.com/4.1.2/) and used them to sign my application but it doesn't work for mr.

Can anyone please explain how I can get those certificates from the `ROM` of my device or is there another solution?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900928/uninstall-app-silently-with-system-priveleges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > To achieve that first you have to obtain the certificates that were used to sign the Android OS installed on the device – a pair of
> >     certificates (.pk8 + x509.pem) – to generate a java certificate.
> >
> > The certificates pair (platform.pk8 + platform.x509.pem) can be found under {Android Source}/build/target/product/security.`
>
> I downloaded the certificate pair from source code for 4.1.2 android
>   version and used them to sign my application but it doesn't work for
>   mr.

I can't answer the question, but I think I know why this failed...

Android sources have 3 or 4 default code and platform signing keys. You grabbed one of the default signing keys, but the OEMs change them when they forked Android. The key is no longer valid. (OEMs are supposed to change the key).

Also see Nikolay Elenkov's [Android Security Internals: An In-Depth Guide to Android’s Security Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593275811). You can probably find it online as a PDF.