# Uninstall app from android device without permission

Tags: java, android, installation, mdm

I developped launcher for an android MDM system. I control this mdm system with Api, so I need help to know how can uninstall/install app into device that use this mdm system in background and without the installer permission.

I also need to delete the apk file from android device storage after the install.

How can I do this programmatically in java?

Any one have solution?

Comment: it may require device rooted & make your app system 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900928/uninstall-app-silently-with-system-privileges

Answer (score 1):

For security purpose without the installer permission we cant install/unistall application in android.

Answer (score 1):

It may require device rooted & make your app system. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900928/uninstall-app-silently-with-system-privileges) for reference.

**Note**: this is **not recomended** if you want publish your app to playstore