# Applications Installed Listener and Suspending internet/3G connections

Tags: android

I am presently working on an android application but am stuck in getting a workable solution. So please I would like to know three things:

```
1. Is there any code to Listen for Installed Applications and also when an Application is being installed?
2. Is there anyway to suspend internet permissions granted to installed applications?
3. Is there anyway to suspend 3G connection in the device without totally disabling it?
```

Please if there is anyone that has an answer to these questions and if possible a code kindly give drop it here. Additionally if one has a better solution that covers these three questions, am also open to it.
Thanks Devs.

Answer (score 0):

Given below is the answer to question 1, Put this in your manifest and you have to then write "YourReceiver" which will receive the intent. With this I'm getting a call to onRecieve, but struggling to find the name/info about the app which got just installed.

```
    <receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Possible duplicate of 
[Receiving package install and uninstall events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events)

Where's the man?