# Track Applications on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

is it possible to keep track of install/uninstall actions of Applications on the Android system? I was not able to find a proper Intent Action or Broadcast event so far.

What I'm searching for an observer for applications like there are observers for Calendar or CallLog changes. Does there exists an CONTENT_URI or Broadcast event?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a broadcast receiver for package install and unistall.

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

For More info go to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events/7471652#7471652)

Comment: uhm - i should have noticed these actions :-/ Thank you for your help!