# Android - BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: android, broadcast

I have seen article [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events)
. Then I try to make a example to catch event when I installed app

This is my code `

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AppInstalled appInstalled = new AppInstalled();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
    registerReceiver(appInstalled, intentFilter);
}

private class AppInstalled extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Application Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}`
```

But it's never show message . Please give me some advice

Comment: Did you add the broadcastreceiver class in the application tag of the manifest file?

Comment: yes , but it same thing

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your receiver into AndroidManifest.xml file under  tag. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

register you receiver in manifest file

```
  <receiver android:name=".AppInstalled">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL has been deprecated in API level 14