# Adobe Air listening to uninstaling event

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have an Adobe Air Android application. I want to know when the app is going to be removed and to do something basic if I catch this event.
Is this possible on adobe air android? thank you!

Comment: Your app is unlikely to be running when it is uninstalled, so there is no way to attach an event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no uninstall event in Adobe Air.

A solution could be to do whatever you want to accomplish every time the [applications exits](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#event:exiting).

```
// make a reference to the NA singleton instance
var nativeApplication = NativeApplication.nativeApplication;

//add an event listener
nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.EXITING,onExitHandler);

function onExitHandler(e){
    //do something
}
```

Another possible solution could be to monitor some URL with a unique device identifier. For example `http://www.domain.com/activity.php?deviceId=1234567890`. You would not know how many apps are installed, but you'd have an idea of how much activity your app is having. I don't know if that would be legal though.

The device identifier can be obtained via a Native Extension such as [this one](http://distriqt.com/native-extensions#application). I'm using it on iOS successfully to identify unique devices.

As for URL monitoring you can use the [URLMonitor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/net/URLMonitor.html) class.

Finally, I'd like to point out that it is indeed possible to do what you are after [using native Java code in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events). Theoretically it should be possible to mimic that functionality developing your own native extension (ANE). [Here's an introduction](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html) on developing your ANE for Android.

Comment: thank you! Unfortunately this is not what I need. I want to know when my app is going to be unnistaled, some statistic informations...

Comment: @tziuka There is no way to do what you want, unfortunately.