# Play Store Download Webhook or Intent?

Tags: android, google-play, bigdata

Simply..

Is there any programmatic way to instantly or in a real-time fashion know when your app has been downloaded from google play store?

I found this service, http://distimo.com  which has a api, but their docs are talking about giving stats within the last month

Also, found this app, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.andlyticsproject, but I want api/realtime webhook like interaction.

Is there any hook within the Android API that can be utilized in knowing within minutes of your app being downloaded.

I understand about getting notified through various means when someone, OPENS, your app but what about just downloads it?

Comment: On download I don't know but on Install (which should happen right after) you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events

Comment: perfect, that helped clarify the flow.... Download, Then Install, Then  App Open, Then event data......., Then Background, Close, Force Close. Are there hooks for basically all these events? I think, yes cept no Download hook yet