# Install application intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to keep a track of my application installs on my server.
Is there any way with which I can know if my app has been successfully installed in a user device.

The condition is without opening the app i need to know this.

Is there any install intent provided by android for it?

Or I have to make a custom installer for it?

any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can actually listen to instalations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events . now you should testy if, this way, your app can listen for its own install intent...

Comment: Call me curious but why would you need to keep track of the installs? You could get the package names of all installed apps right?

Comment: I just need to know if my application is installed or not. As it wont be available on play store. It is the clien'ts requirement

Comment: Are you trying to find out if the application has previously been installed, or trying to do something at the moment it is installed?

Comment: I dun want to know if it is previously installed. What I want is during or after installation a URL to be hit with which I can know that my app has been installed considering the scenario that the app has not been opened once.