# how to delete folder on SD card while app is uninstalling from phone

Tags: android, android-service, android-file

while installing app on phone i am creating directory using new `File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myfoldername/Filename.db");`

But now i want to delete folder i.e. ***myfoldername***  from SD card, while app is getting uninstalled.
I  read [deletion through broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events) but still i unable to delete folder from SD card.

Answer (score 4):

That is not possible. Your app does not get control at uninstall time.

You should switch to putting your files on external storage in `getExternalFilesDir()` and/or `getExternalCacheDir()` (methods on `Context`, such as your `Activity`). Those directories, along with your internal storage, are all removed automatically upon an uninstall.

Comment: my app doesn't have fixed location ,i mean if sd card is not present then it creates folder on internal storage .So how to handle that

Comment: @inj3ct0r: Internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`) is automatically deleted on uninstall. You do not need to do anything. Note that your original question is not about [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), but instead is about [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). None of this has anything to do with [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).