# Apps refresh on launch Android

Tags: java, android, launcher

I've built and Android launcher and have the list of installed apps showing, and am able to delete on long press but after I delete and app the icon stays in the drawer.

Any ideas on how to have the list refresh after the deletion happens?

Thanks

Edit 1 - Heres my code for the app deletion

```
 @Override
public void onGridItemLongClick(GridView g, View v, int position, long id) {
    AppModel app = (AppModel) getGridAdapter().getItem(position);
    if (app != null) {
        Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+app.getApplicationPackageName());
        Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);

        if (uninstallIntent != null) {
            startActivity(uninstallIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to answer that without code?

Comment: @GabeSechan added my code for the deletion.... sorry

Comment: So you aren't deleting it yourself, you're subcontracting.  In that case I'd set a listener for uninstall events and refresh your gridview when you get one.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events

Comment: I'm newer to development, I didn't realize I could delete it myself without subcontracting it... Thanks I'll take a loot

Comment: You can, but you pretty much need to be a system app.  It requires secure permissions.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, I appreciate the point in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same task done for my app,

First you need to create extends BroadcastReceiver class and register in Manifest,

**InstallUninstallReceiver.java**

```
  public class InstallUninstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private static final String TAG = InstallUninstallReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
           startLoaderAsyncTask();
        }
private LoaderAsyncTask mLoaderAsyncTask;
private void startLoaderAsyncTask()
    {
        if(mLoaderAsyncTask != null)
        {
            mLoaderAsyncTask.cancel(true);
            mLoaderAsyncTask = null;
        }
        if(mLoaderAsyncTask == null)
            mLoaderAsyncTask = new LoaderAsyncTask();
        mLoaderAsyncTask.execute();
    }
    }
```

**AndriodManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".InstallUninstallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Above code will trigger when app install and uninstall event occur on that time you will call asyntask and update your adapter list.

**LoaderAsyncTask.java**

```
public class LoaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, PackageInfo, Void> {
    ProgressDialog mDialog;
    private ArrayList<PackageInfo> mList = new ArrayList();
    public LoaderAsyncTask()
    {
        mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity, "Loading", "Pls wait a moment...");
        mList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try
        {
            refreshAppList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void refreshAppList() {
        PackageManager pkgMgr = mActivity.getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> pgs = pkgMgr.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        for (int i = 0; i < pgs.size(); i++) 
        {
                    if(isCancelled())
                        break;
                    PackageInfo p = pgs.get(i);
                   mList.add(p);
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        mDialog.dismiss();
      //  mGridAdapter.setData(mList);//now you will get update app list , set to your GridAdapter refresh the Launcher.
    }
}
```