# Earn point on App install Android

Tags: android, affiliate

I want to develop an Android Application, Where user can install application from a link(redirect to play store) and earn points.
and i can track following activity of user:

- User has installed application or not?
- After installed if S/He use application for 5 mins, then credit few points in their account.

Comment: `User has installed application or not?` - check the list of installed applications. `if S/He use application for 5 mins` - no way to do that. You have no access to see which apps have user used. (I might mistaken about the last)

Answer (score 1):

You can create receiver for package installed event, check if new package name is the package name of the application You want your user to install.
[Receiving package install and uninstall events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events)

You should also keep the time of installation and check if it is older then 5 mins when You get uninstall event for this package

Comment: Thanx Pavel, 
There are a lot app in market, they do the same thing, There must an alternative of this.
Just want to know how do they do?