# Call back on new App install

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to perform some action in my app when a new other application is installed in the device.

Is there any way I can do that? TIA

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7471652/3333848

Comment: Im not sure what you want here, can you please try explain it more detailed. What i read here sounds really shady.

Comment: what you exactly want to do explain please..

Comment: Yeah, @Lunar, thats what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should register for a broadcast when a package is added/removed, where android system broadcast a message to the all the registered apps.

so in your manifest add a broadcast receiver.

```
<receiver android:name=".AppListener">
            <intent-filter android:priority="{highInteger}">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Where `AppListener` is your java class where in onReceive() you can perform the desired operation.

Comment for any further doubts.