# API level 26 and above: How to detect wether an app is installed or not?

Tags: android, installation, android-8.0-oreo

We have Android app which detects if apps are installed/ uninstalled on device or not.
with the help of manifest file which is as below:

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
```

The android app receives broadcast from internal systems and send it to our servers.

But after API 26 android OS is not giving broadcast for Package_Installed.

Dose anyone know how to detect the app installation after API lever 26.

Comment: what is your app's targetSdkVersion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46489255/115145

Answer (score 1):

Apps that target Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest. Apps will still receive broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver() and that context is still valid.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts