# How to show window when user click on uninstall button of any app

Tags: android

I'm working an app called 'Prevent Uninstall', in this app user creates 4 digit pin and I'm going to save this pin in sharedpreferences. My requirement is when user clicks uninstall button of any application a popup or window should be displayed to confirm the pin which is already created in my application. So is it possible?, if possible please help me, i got stuck at this point.

hello guys finally i have found a solution below..

first get the current activity on foreground

```
public boolean isConcernedAppIsInForeground() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> task = manager.getRunningTasks(5);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 20) {
        if (task.size() > 0) {
            ComponentName componentInfo = task.get(0).topActivity;
            for (int i = 0; pakageName != null && i < pakageName.size(); i++) {
                if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals("com.google.android.packageinstaller")) {
                    currentApp_for = pakageName.get(i);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; pakageName != null && i < pakageName.size(); i++) {
            if (retriveNewApp().equals("com.google.android.packageinstaller")) {
                currentApp_for = pakageName.get(i);
                Log.e("DSSDSDCSDC", currentApp_for + " LLLLLL::::");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

To get the current activity on foreground  above api level 21+ use this code

```
private String retriveNewApp() {
    String currentApp_for_ = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> applist = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time);
        if (applist != null && applist.size() > 0) {
            SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : applist) {
                mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
            }
            if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                currentApp_for_ = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
            }
            Log.e(">>>>>>>>>><<<", "Current App in foreground is: " + currentApp_for_);
        } else {
            Log.e("CCC>>C>C>C>", "User not given the permission: " + currentApp_for_);
        }


    }
    return currentApp_for_;
}
```

Important permission

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

now check the current activity is in foreground or not using service

```
    if (isConcernedAppIsInForeground()) {
     if (!currentApp.matches(previousApp)) {
        // if matches do your activity here..
startActivity(newIntent(context,Draw_Lock.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

       previousApp = currentApp;
            }
        }
   }
```

**Note**: **When user clicks on uninstall button of any app alert dialog popups which is known as 'com.google.android.packageinstaller' activity** check weather this activity is in foreground or not using service class

Comment: Yes, it's possible in the sense that you need to register a broadcast listener. Check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events

Comment: Tq sir @Uday, but this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events works only when user install the app ,but i need when user clicks on uninstall button of any app. i have found the solution  here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733805/how-to-show-window-when-user-click-on-uninstall-button-of-any-app